# how to change phpmyadmin titlebar and show only domain?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, titlebar

- In default PHPMyAdmin showing  `<domain> |  <Table> <column> PHPMyAdmin 4.9.5deb` on title bar in my browser,
- I need to remove those things and show only `domain www.example.com` or `index.php`
- I'm referring to this document: https://web.njit.edu/mysql/phpMyAdmin/doc/html/config.html#cfg_Servers_verbose
- this one is my first Stackoverflow question, please guide me for this

Comment: Please be clear in your question, and do say what your intention are, and why  (referring to "and show only domain .... or ....")

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Setting/Features/Page titles` and change the settings.

Or, alternativly, add this to `config.inc.php`:

```
$cfg['TitleDefault'] = "DEFAULT TITLE1";
$cfg['TitleTable'] = "DEFAULT TITLE2";
$cfg['TitleDatabase'] = "DEFAULT TITLE3";
$cfg['TitleServer'] = "DEFAULT TITLE4";
```

(and, of course, change the `DEFAULT TITLEx` to the thing you want to show).

Changing all default titles to `"@HTTP_HOST@"` will only show the hostname, in my case `localhost`.

And, finally, a link to the docs: https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#page-titles